# ZeroMQ REQ-REP not working

Tags: linux, zeromq

I'm trying to use ZeroMQ for data exchange between my programs. My system consists of two parts: client (REQ) written on C# and running on Windows and server (REP) written in C++ and running on linux ubuntu.

The client sends a request, server catches it, processes and sends a reply. The reply is never delivered.

In the minimal test case client and server simply sends empty messages, so the problem isn't in the message construction or processing code.

If I change the roles, and run server on Windows and Client on Linux, everything works OK. If I start PUB server on Linux and the SUB client on Windows, none of the messages is delivered.

I use Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64, ZeroMQ 4.0.3 and g++ 4.6.3 on server side and Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013 RC and clrzmq NuGet package 2.2.5 on the client side.

Does anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: show code, otherwise, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I get it. I had to use older version of ZMQ on the server