# zeromq: using a linux [REP] and windows [REQ] connection, no message arrives

Tags: c++, linux, windows, zeromq

I am trying to send messages from a windows client to a linux server using the REQ/REP pattern with ZeroMQ. The server side code is the [hwserver.cpp](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/hwserver.cpp) code from the examples of the 0MQ guide. And for the client side I also use the example code [hwclient.cpp](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/hwclient.cpp).

Now the problem at hand is the following. If I use a Linux server and client I am able to send messages, receive them and send a reply back which is also received. When the server and client are both run in Windows I also can receive and send messages. If the server is running in Windows and the client is running in Linux it also works. These tests make me think I have at least the correct IP adresses.

When I try to use a Linux server and a Windows clien, the messages that are send do not arrive at the server. And I don't know what could cause this, since the reverse with a Windows server + Linux client works perfectly. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599831/zeromq-req-rep-not-working) but the solution posted there did not work.

I use Fedora 20 with g++ 4.8.3 and Windows 8 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Is there an option that has to be flagged when doing this kind of 0MQ connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Once ZeroMQ version numbers match, there need not be any further "magic-switch" for Window$

n.b.:

```
socket.connect ("tcp://<_aUbuntuHOST_IpADRESS_>:5555"); // Do W8 allow outbound tcp:5555 connection in the security policy in effect?
```

May you proof that the Win integrated firewall policies ( explicit security settings permit exceptions ) do allow a process to request + use an outgoing tcp connection on the specified port number?

May reverse `.bind()` / `.connect()` on `REQ`/`REP` sides to remain on the same situation as that was working once you had Ubuntu.**`REQ`** ( with `.connect()` ) and the W8.**`REP`** ( with `.bind()` ) so the W8.**`REQ`**  would again `.bind()` ( which you reported that worked fine ) & Ubuntu.**`REP`** would `.connect()`